# Order important update mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that have a primary key "P", and a unique key "U", suppose that "U" have no rows with the value 35, and because of the business rule i need to update all "U" > 35 to 
"U" - 1.

My question is: If I do that without caring about the order of the update, during the update two rows could have the same value of "U".

Is this a problem?

I mean MySQL check the unique constraint at the end of the update or during the update?
If this update will fail can I do it by:

```
UPDATE `Table` `y`
INNER JOIN (
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `U` > 35 ORDER BY `U`) AS `x`
ON `x`.`P` = `y`.`P`
SET `y`.`U` = `y`.`U` - 1
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience mysql will check unique constraint during updation and will not allow any duplicity even multiple rows updation in single update command. You can check with any dummy table.